# How to run the script after completion of foreach loop in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I want to run the script after the foreach loop complete its execution,

```
// Code goes here
var app=angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$timeout,$q){
  var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
  var log = [];
  angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
   $timeout(function () {
       console.log('foreach running');
       log.push(key + ': ' + value);
    }, 50000);
  });
  $q.all(log).then(function(){
    console.log(log);  
  })


})
```

In the above code the `log` array values are created in `forEach` loop I want to print the values in `log` array after the `foreach` execution completed, how should I do it?

**Edit**

when I used `$timeout` inside `angulr.forEach` the `console.log` fired before the completion of `angular.forEach` cycle, why so? where can I refer whether the call is synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
  var log = [];
  var promises = [];
  angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
   var defer = $q.defer();
   promises.push(defer.promise);
   $timeout(function () {
       console.log('foreach running');
       log.push(key + ': ' + value);
       defer.resolve();
    }, 50000);
  });
  $q.all(promises).then(function(){
    console.log(log);  
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, please can you explain little, can we achieve the result without using variable `promises` and I want to know is `angular.forEach` synchronous call or asynchronous call? `$timeout` is  asynchronous call right?

Comment: angular.forEach is sync. $timeout is async. You can do it without variable 'promises' - you can do pretty wahtever, but it wont be better code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, when I used `$timeout` inside `angulr.forEach` the console.log fired before the `angular.forEach` cycle completion why so? where can I refer whether the call is synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

since you have no asynchronized code running no need for $q so you can simply put console.log(log) after the loop, it will certainly be running after the loop is finished and the code would be like that

```
var app=angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope,$timeout,$q){
  var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
  var log = [];
  for (var key in values) {
    log.push({[key]:values[key]});
  };
  console.log(log);
});
```

Comment: Is $http calls only the asynchronus call? , I want to know what will be the result if I have the huge value in `values` object it will take time to iterate the object, is it? while that call is running console log could be called before that execution right? or will it be the synchronous call? I have used the angular.forEach to iterate the `values` does angular.forEach is an asynchronous call or not?

Comment: angular.forEach is synchronous function for sure

Comment: Thanks for your response, Where can we refer this? if its synchronous call the console.log should fire after the execution of angular.forEach but when I used `$timeout` inside `angulr.forEach` the console.log fired before the angular.forEach cycle completion